# Problems displaying more than one tweet using JS and Twitter API

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I'm trying to use a custom twitter status list on a site, using js and the Twitter API. However, a problem seems to arise with the number of tweets displaying (controlled by the suffix `&count=x`).  Although it shows one tweet just fine when it ends `&count=1`, and will happily show ten tweets with `&count=10` or even all of the tweets when `&count=x` is removed completely from the code, for some reason it refuses to show two, three or four tweets. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Thanks very much. Code I'm using is below.

http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/twitter_username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3